# Pyspark - Window and shuffle behavior

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to know if a Window used x times will perform x times shuffle of the data.

Example :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('col_a').orderBy('date')

df = df.withColumn('new_col_1', F.lag('col_b').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('new_col_2', F.row_number().over(w))
```

Will this code perform 1 shuffle of the data because there's 1 Window ?
Or 2 shuffle of the data because the Window is used twice ?

If the answer is 2 shuffle, would a repartitioning by col_a reduce the amount of shuffle to 1 like in below code example ?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy(col_a).orderBy('date')

df = df.repartition('col_a')
df = df.withColumn('new_col_1', F.lag('col_b').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('new_col_2', F.row_number().over(w))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we display how spark will compute this dataframe with `explain`, we get the following execution plan:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('col_a').orderBy('date')

df = df.withColumn('new_col_1', F.lag('col_b').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('new_col_2', F.row_number().over(w))

df.explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# Window [lag(col_b#2, -1, null) windowspecdefinition(col_a#1L, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS new_col_1#19, row_number() windowspecdefinition(col_a#1L, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS new_col_2#25], [col_a#1L], [date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST]
# +- *(2) Sort [col_a#1L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#    +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_a#1L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#23]
#       +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[date#0,col_a#1L,col_b#2]
```

As you can see, there is only one `Exchange` (meaning one shuffle) step. **So there is only one shuffle if you reuse your window to compute several columns**, if there is no shuffle between those computation. Moreover, there is only one `Window` step, meaning that the two columns using window are actually computed during the same step and not one after other.

#### Others cases

If we repartition by `col_a` before computing columns windows, the execution plan is the same than without repartition:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('col_a').orderBy('date')

df = df.repartition('col_a')
df = df.withColumn('new_col_1', F.lag('col_b').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('new_col_2', F.row_number().over(w))

df.explain()

# == Physical Plan ==
# Window [lag(col_b#2, -1, null) windowspecdefinition(col_a#1L, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS new_col_1#19, row_number() windowspecdefinition(col_a#1L, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS new_col_2#25], [col_a#1L], [date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST]
# +- *(2) Sort [col_a#1L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#    +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_a#1L, 200), REPARTITION, [id=#26]
#       +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[date#0,col_a#1L,col_b#2]
```

If we repartition by `col_a` between the two column computations that use window, the two columns are no longer computed in the same step:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('col_a').orderBy('date')

df = df.withColumn('new_col_1', F.lag('col_b').over(w))
df = df.repartition('col_a')
df = df.withColumn('new_col_2', F.row_number().over(w))

df.explain()

# == Physical Plan ==
# Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(col_a#1L, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS new_col_2#25], [col_a#1L], [date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST]
# +- Window [lag(col_b#2, -1, null) windowspecdefinition(col_a#1L, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS new_col_1#19], [col_a#1L], [date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST]
#    +- *(2) Sort [col_a#1L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#       +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_a#1L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#33]
#          +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[date#0,col_a#1L,col_b#2]
```

if we repartition by `col_b` between the two window column computations, we get 3 shuffles. So using the same window trigger one shuffle only if there is no repartition/shuffle using other columns between window column computations:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('col_a').orderBy('date')

df = df.withColumn('new_col_1', F.lag('col_b').over(w))
df = df.repartition('col_b')
df = df.withColumn('new_col_2', F.row_number().over(w))

df.explain()

# == Physical Plan ==
# Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(col_a#1L, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS new_col_2#25], [col_a#1L], [date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST]
# +- *(3) Sort [col_a#1L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#    +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_a#1L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#42]
#       +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_b#2, 200), REPARTITION, [id=#41]
#          +- Window [lag(col_b#2, -1, null) windowspecdefinition(col_a#1L, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS new_col_1#19], [col_a#1L], [date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST]
#             +- *(2) Sort [col_a#1L ASC NULLS FIRST, date#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#                +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col_a#1L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#36]
#                   +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[date#0,col_a#1L,col_b#2]
```

Comment: Why there is partitioning with col_a in last plan at row#3 considering the partitioning  is required on col_b

Comment: In last plan, the partitionning at row#3 is due to the window by `col_a` and not by partition by `col_b`. Actually you have 3 partitionning, a first partitionning by `col_a` at row#7, a second partitionning by `col_b` at row#4, and a final partionning by `col_a` at row#3. The only one tagged as `REPARTITION` is the one at row#4, corresponding to `df.repartition('col_b')`, the others are due to window and are tagged as `ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS`